# Best practices to handle errors in GCP Dataflow pipelines

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a GCP Datapipeline running and I am wondering what are the best ways to handle errors. The pipeline looks like this

```
read_from_pubsub --> business_logic_ParDo() --> write_to_bigquery
```

- While testing, I have noticed that [ParDo being stuck](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#processing-stuck). Though I was able to resolve the issue but i noticed that it made my pipeline stuck, So what should be the best approach to handle this?
- What should my ParDo function do if the business logic fails? I don't want to write to big_query partial data.

Can't think of any other error scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [dead letter pattern](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/handling-invalid-inputs-in-dataflow) to handle unrecoverable errors in business logic. As for aborting stuck records, you could try something like [func-timeout](https://pypi.org/project/func-timeout/), but that could be expensive to use on every element.